# Not working string comparison between vector element and a txt file line

Tags: c++, string, vector, compare, getline

```
while (file.good())
{
    for (vector <string>::iterator i = v1.begin(); i != v1.end();)
    {
        getline(file, sTmp);
        if (sTmp != *i)
        {
            v2.push_back(sTmp);
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

I already filled the v1 with file names in the current directory and just want to insert the names from txt file that do not match with v1 elements (v1 and v2 are string vectors). The above code looks logical but doesn't work. I get all files from txt file in v2, not the different ones.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: @talnicolas Why?  `==` and `!=` work perfectly well.

Comment: You're doing `getline()` for every element `v1`. You'd do that if you wanted to compare pairs of `line from file` and `string from vector`, but perhaps you want to compare each line with every vector element?

Comment: [`while (file.good())` is almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Where did you learn to do that?

Comment: From cplusplus.com as standart function to check the integrity of the file or its eof.

Comment: @1000Gbps Then stay away from that site.  It's authors don't know C++.

Comment: Ok, can you suggest which online source to read where its code examples are good?

Comment: @1000Gbps: You need [_these_ resources](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources). And please @notify people when you reply to them. `

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code.  The one you're seeing is due
to the fact that you read a new line from the file for every element in
`v1`, and compare that line with only the current element in `v1`; you
probably want to move the `getline` out of the inner loop, something
like:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( file, line ) ) {
    std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator pos
            = std::find( v1.begin(), v1.end(), line );
    if ( pos != v1.end() ) {
        v2.push_back( line );
    }
}
```

This also solves a second major problem: you weren't testing that the
call to `getline` succeeded before using its results.
(`std::ios_base::good()` is probably the most useless function in the
standard.  I've yet to find a case where calling it would be
appropriate.)

Comment: Just tested your version and this print only the elements of v1, where my needs are to print elements of v2 that are not equal of v1 (taken from txt file). The idea is to print the file names that are from this txt file and to ignore those that are equal with v1 elements ... Pretty sad :\

Comment: Shouldn't it probably be `if (pos == v1.end())` for what OP wants?

Comment: @jrok Maybe.  I'm not too clear about what he wanted (but what you suggest actually sounds right---more so than what I wrote, anyway).

Comment: @jrok, if (pos == v1.end()) gives my original result - prints the whole txt file through the vector :\

Comment: @1000Gbps That means that either `v1` is empty or that all files differ.

Comment: Hmm, well it's not empy cause I printed the size and elements in console to be sure. Checked also if the first element (IPs ie 10.10.1.2) of v1 is in the txt file and it's there >.< Pushbacking data in v1 elements is done in my question for merging - using FILE * pipe = _popen() output. Is this a bad way to fill this data? Char per char the output is equal with matching lines in txt file ...

Comment: I'll guess: You don't filter out newline characters you get from _popen. `getline()` OTOH removes them; that would explain the matter.

Comment: What should I do to filter them? I thought that when reading from char array the \n is replaced with \0 ?

Comment: Perhaps you're better off with asking another question, so you can show some code. Let's stop spamming James' inbox.

Comment: Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/users/947836/jrok I found the main cause of the problem - those dangerous \n :)

 `for (vector <string>::iterator i = v1.begin(); i != v1.end(); ++i)
 {
  stmp = *i;
  stmp.resize(stmp.size() - 1);
  string line;
  while (getline(file, line))
  {
   //vector <string>::const_iterator pos = find(v1.begin(), v1.end(), line);
   if (stmp == line)
   {
    continue;
   }
   else
   {
    v2.push_back(line);
   }
  }
 }`

 Can't understand why some lines are only in v1 as should be, but other lines are in both v1 and v2 :\